# How to convert a decimal (2^x) to binary?

Tags: binary

Everything will be considered in 2's complement.

<strike>So from my understanding, since binary is base 2:</strike>

2<sup>36</sup> (decimal) = 100100<sub>2</sub> (binary)

Apparently, my understanding was not very understanding.

2<sup>36</sup> = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub> (36 0's)

Would the bottom way still work to find 2<sup>-36</sup>?

Essentially: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub> ALSO after the inversions and addition of a 1

Would that mean 2<sup>-36</sup> in decimal would essentially be inverting and adding a 1 to the original:

100100<sub>2</sub> --> 011011<sub>2</sub> --> 011100<sub>2</sub>

Then another thing is what would happen for:

5 x 2<sup>-23</sup> (decimal) = ??? (binary)

I'm assuming something along the lines of binary multiplication, but not too sure about it.

Comment: Should not be $$2^{36}=(10000\cdots 0000)_2$$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Oh...2^36 is literally one 1 and thirty-six 0's? How would that work for 2^-36?

Comment: Yes, definitely. For example consider $10^{10}=10000000000$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Hrm...I see, should I invert and add 1, which essentially ends up as the same number for 2^-36?

Comment: Note that $2^{-6} = 0.000\ 001_2$, hence, $3 \times 2^{-6} = (11 \times 0.000\ 001)_2 = 0.000\ 011_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not hard to find a binary expansion for a positive integer by consecutively dividing it by $2$. For a positive fractional less than $1$, namely $x$, we can write the binary expansion by consecutively multiplying it by $2$. For example, let $x={1\over 3}$. Then $$x_1=\lfloor2x\rfloor=\lfloor{2\over 3}\rfloor=0\\x_2=\lfloor4x\rfloor-x_1=1\\x_3=0\\\vdots$$therefore$${1\over 3}=(0.01010101\cdots)_2$$

**So, what about $1\over 2^n$**?